# The data types varchar and ntext are incompatible in the add operator with hibernate

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

I've following as a part of query

```
nameQuery = " AND (lower(templateInformation.name) LIKE lower('%' || :name || '%'))";
```

when only this name parameter exceed 4001 characters it will throw following exception.

```
Caused by: se.cambio.platform.sdk.common.service.ServiceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet [at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert():54], Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The data types varchar and ntext are incompatible in the add operator. [at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic():372]
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2886)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2328)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:638)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQLQuery(JtdsStatement.java:506)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:979)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:93)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:56)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2036)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1836)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1815)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:899)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2522)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2508)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2338)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2333)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:490)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1269)
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
```

I found this [article](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/12/04/sql-server-fix-error-402-the-data-types-ntext-and-varchar-are-incompatible-in-the-equal-to-operator/) explain why this happened generally. But in my case it wont thorw any thing if name parameter have characters less than or equal 4001. And table column type is nvarchar(255).
Can somebody explain this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function to concatenate strings in MySQL

> Returns the string that results from concatenating the arguments. May
>   have one or more arguments.

Comment: :could you please elaborate that? what should i concatenate?

Comment: I think your pronlem exists here "LIKE lower('%' || :name || '%')" where you are concatenating the '%' and the name variable and the ending '%'

Comment: I changed the code as "LIKE lower(concat('%', :name , '%'))" but still it throws the same exception. Any ideas?